# Custom file open in android

Tags: android, file, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to open custom file type (.mia) using my app. I have tried this way

```
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.mia"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.mia"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.mia"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.mia"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

It works perfectly in Marshmallow and Jelly bean. But in lollipop it not open work when I click a download file from notification bar. But work when I open from any file manager. How can I show my app when user click download file in the notification bar?

Comment: What solution did you come up with?  I am wondering the same right now...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a separate `intent-filter` for each `data` element:

```xml
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.mia"
            android:mimeType="*/*"/>
     </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.mia"
            android:mimeType="*/*"/>
     </intent-filter>
     ...
     ...
</activity>
```